# how to draw histogram graph in r with non-numeric time data?

Tags: r

I got data like this:

```
serialno   departure_time   mode
1            5:34           walk
2            9:03           bus
3            6:10           car
4            7:50           car
5            9:00           car
```

I want to draw histogram graph and count frequency about variable departure_time. The x-axis will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and the y-axis will be frequency.

thanks!

Comment: This is not clear for me. What should the x axis represent? And what do you whant to count?

Comment: sorry! wrong typing. it should be y-axis and x-axis

Comment: Not the typing is the problem. Do you want to count the full hours. Count frequency about variable dperture_time e.g. `5:34` 1 times ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract hours from `departure_time` and use it to plot.

Here are couple of ways to do that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(hours = sub(':.*', '', departure_time)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(hours, n) +  geom_col()
```

Or

```
df %>%
  mutate(hours = as.numeric(sub(':.*', '', departure_time))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(hours) +  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: one more question, do you know how to add a curve(reflect the histogram trend) in this histogram graph? thank you!

Comment: Maybe this will he helpful `df %>%
  mutate(hours = as.numeric(sub(':.*', '', departure_time))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(hours) +  geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(x=hours,y=..density..))` Or you can also ask a new question for this.